# Android emulator not responding problem on the AMD process for Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-emulator, mono

When I update my windows to windows 11, I notice about when I run the android emulator for my Xamarin project, it freeze and said not responding.

[image]

I try these items below but won’t fix my problem :

1. reduce ram size of emulator device
2. reduce the resolution of emulator device
3. reinstall Android SDK
4. reinstall visual studio
   My Virtual Machine Platform and Hyper-V are enabled in my windows features.

My emulator detail is :

> OS: Android 12
>
> Ram: 4GB
>
> Resolution : 1080x2340 pixels
>
> Google Services: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the AMD process, we need to make clear to the visual studio that we use the AMD process and it should change the emulator behavior to our process.

First of all like I said we need to make sure the `Virtual Machine Platform` and `Hyper-V` are enabled because it’s necessary to run an android emulator in a visual studio.

[image]

Second, We need to make sure that `Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors` is selected in the visual studio.

**Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for the AMD Processors:**

```
Visual Studio > Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager > Tools > Extras > Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors
```

[image]

Third, `Restart` your visual studio and you’re good to go and enjoy your android emulator on the AMD Processors.