# AMD Processor Xamarin Application

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-emulator, amd-processor

I am new to Xamarin forms and I'd like to create a simple mobile application with it. I'm trying to use the Android emulator in order to view the application that I'm working on in real time. The problem is, the emulator recommends that my PC has an intel processor to run the emulator. I have an AMD processor and by no means would I say it's bad , but when I open up the emulator, the android emulator won't even start and it is just sitting on a black screen.

Is there any way to use the Android emulator on Xamarin with an AMD CPU? If so could someone please tell me how? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here.

[Android emulator not responding problem on the AMD process for Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71460025/android-emulator-not-responding-problem-on-the-amd-process-for-xamarin)

https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver.

The android emulators on AMD cpus do work they are just slow.

Working on Xamarin myself, i found it easier to use an android device as my debugging tool.